# multicore and data.table in R

Tags: r, fork, multicore, data.table

I am attempting to use `multicore` function `parallel` with `data.table` and am unable to quite come up with the right way to do this.  Code:

```
require(multicore)
require(data.table)
dtb = data.table(a=1:10, b=1:2)
x = dtb[,parallel(a+1),by=b]

> x
   b   pid fd
1: 1 12243  3
2: 1 12243  6
3: 2 12247  4
4: 2 12247  8
```

I would like to call `collect()` on this but these are no longer `parallel` objects.  How should one do this?

Comment: What's wrong with `x = dtb[, collect(parallel(a+1)),by=b]`?

Comment: collect waits for parallel to finish

Comment: @alex it's difficult to understand why collect() waiting for parallel() is a problem. It's also difficult to extrapolate your example to a real problem, and therefore know what you really want from this. Can you help us understand?

Answer (score 3):

I think this is along the lines of what you want:

```
collect(dtb[, list(jobs = list(parallel(a+1))), by = b][, jobs])
```

The reason you didn't have `parallel` objects any more and couldn't run a `collect` is because you were converting them *to* a `list`, instead of storing them *in* a list, which is what I did above.