# Changing the dimensions of a data frame in R

Tags: r, plyr, data-manipulation

I have a data set with dozens of columns and thousands of rows. Here I present just a toy example:

```
trN <- c(0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1)
tt <- c(1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4)
varX <- c(1,5,NA,9,2,NA,8,4)
d <- as.data.frame(cbind(trN, tt, varX))
```

The first thing that I do is to spline interpolate column `varX` as a function of column `tt` for each `trN`. An operation that is easily done with `ddply` from the `plyr` package.

```
ddply(d, .(trN), mutate, varXint = spline(tt, varX, xout = tt)$y)
```

But suppose that I would like to also change the dimension (number of rows) of the new data frame. For instance, I would like to have a set of values specifying where interpolation is to take place (`xout`) that has a different length then `tt`. Obviously, the approach here below doesn't work, because with `mutate` the new column needs to have the same length as the columns of the original data frame:

```
ddply(d, .(trN), mutate, varXint = spline(tt, varX, xout = seq(1, 4, by = 1.5))$y)
```

Does anyone have a suitable solution or any kind of suggestion? I would prefer to have a solution based on the `plyr` package, because I can take advantage of the implemented parallelization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try a simple `data.table` first:

```
library(data.table)
dt = data.table(d)

# I added xout since I assumed you want that
dt[, list(varXint = spline(tt, varX, xout = seq(1, 4, by = .5))$y,
          xout = seq(1, 4, 0.5)),
     by = trN]
#    trN  varXint xout
# 1:   0 1.000000  1.0
# 2:   0 3.166667  1.5
# 3:   0 5.000000  2.0
# 4:   0 6.500000  2.5
# 5:   0 7.666667  3.0
# 6:   0 8.500000  3.5
# 7:   0 9.000000  4.0
# 8:   1 2.000000  1.0
# 9:   1 5.250000  1.5
#10:   1 7.333333  2.0
#11:   1 8.250000  2.5
#12:   1 8.000000  3.0
#13:   1 6.583333  3.5
#14:   1 4.000000  4.0
```

And if your bottleneck is indeed the inside computation vs just the grouping issue, then check out e.g. [multicore and data.table in R](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14697670/817778) or [data.table and parallel computing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14759905/data-table-and-parallel-computing)

Comment: Thanks. Since I never used `data.table` before I was wondering if it is possible to define `xout` before `varXint` and then use it inside the spline function. I'm asking because my `xout` variable will be used in a dozen of spline interpolations and it doesn't make much sense to recompute it over and over again.

Comment: @VLC you can use full expressions in the second argument of `[.data.table`, so you can do smth like this: `dt[, {tmp = seq(1, 4, 0.5); some_computation(tmp); list(varXint = spline(..., xout = tmp), xout = tmp)}, by = trN]`